# Compare values of return type Boolean and Integer

Tags: java, integer, boolean

I have a scenario where an object receiving from UI passes a Boolean value and this is stored in database as an Integer like TRUE=1 and FALSE=0. Now when the flag is changed for ex to FALSE i need to compare its integer value if its 0 then do nothing if 1 then change to 0 and update. The one way is below, but still there maybe a better way to do this.

```
class AClient {
    static Boolean x;
}
class BServer {
    static Integer y;
}
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClient.x = Boolean.TRUE;
        BServer.y = 0;
        System.out.println(storedValues());
    }
    private static Boolean storedValues() {
        if (AClient.x) {
            if (BServer.y.equals(new Integer(1))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (BServer.y.equals(new Integer(1))) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `storedValues` method can be reduced to:

```
return AClient.x.equals(BServer.y.equals(1));
```

If `x` and `y` don't need to ever be null, I would replace them with primitives instead of the wrapper class, then `storedValues` could look like this:

```
return BServer.y == 1 == AClient.x;
```

You could also change the return type of `storedValues` to `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a shorter way to write it:

Instead of:

```
if (BServer.y.equals(new Integer(1))) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

write :

```
return (BServer.y == 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Ummm, why even use the ternary operator at all?